# Check if value in array in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, template-engine

Is there any way to check if a value is in an array in an angular template? I'm looking to something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{'myClass':1 in [1,2,5]}">Yay</div>
```

Where myClass is applied if 1 is in the array.

Is this possible?

And as an aside, what templating engine exactly is used with Angularjs? Where can I find documentation for it? Whenever I try and search (even official docs), I only seem to turn up docs on directives or data binding.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` to test whether a value is in an array and then use it inside your `ngClass` like this (to conditionally add "newclass"):

```
<div ng-class="{'newclass':([1,2,5].indexOf(2) > -1)}">Yay</div>
```

Or more likely you'll want to test against an array on your scope:

```
<div ng-class="{'newclass':(tarray.indexOf(1) > -1)}">Yay</div>
```

Assuming, for instance, you have declared `tarray` in your controller:

```
$scope.tarray=[1,2,5];
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D9bev/1/)

As far as a template engine, it's built in to Angular.  So there's not really something separate to search for.  But here's the [top level template docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)  and there's some good [video tutorials here](https://egghead.io/lessons) that cover templates (for instance the first one is on data binding) as well as much more.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for - didn't realize quite how much JS I could use in the templates.

Comment: Can I use findIndex here? like if I do have an array $scope.tarray=[{1},{2},{5}]; then how would I have to write syntax?

Answer (score 15):

You can create a filter to check this. Something like:

```
app.filter('inArray', function() {
    return function(array, value) {
        return array.indexOf(value) !== -1;
    };
});
```

Then you can use this in your template with:

```
<div ng-class="{'newclass': tarray | inArray : 1}">Yay</div>
```

The advantage to this is that it makes your template more readable.

Comment: Nice solution, but I needed to add parenthesis around the filter expression to avoid an angular syntax error. `<div ng-class="{'newclass': (tarray | inArray : 1)}">Yay</div>`

Comment: You could add the verification if `array` is an `Array` object (it might not always be an array, especially on initialization): `return Array.isArray(array) && array.indexOf(value) !== -1;`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{'myClass':  !!~[1,2,5].indexOf(1)}"
```

if the value isn't in array you get 0 therefore with !!
you get false

Comment: indexOf returns -1 when the item is not in the array

Comment: @Gruff Bunny ~[1,2,5].indexOf(3) with the bit operations you get 0

Comment: Oops - didn't see the not there - i do apologise

Comment: Great idea- but unfortunately bitwise operators are not supported in Angular expressions:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2838